# memcached is not working is number of rows is more than 45,000 in Django

Tags: django, memcached

There are **50000** rows in MySQL with four fields. If i use memcached it is not working if rows are greater then **45398**. If i use less than that memcached is working. like if i mention **result[45397]** in **cache.set** it works but if i mention more than that memcached will not work.I also edited size in memcached.conf but there is no change. Here is my code. please help me with solution.

```
cache_key1="wen11"
result1 = cache.get(cache_key1)
cache_time=86400

if not result1: 
    result=fashion('title','product_id','color','brand')
    cache.set(cache_key1,result,cache_time)
    print "first time"
```

Comment: What does "will not work" mean? What do you see?

Comment: This might help http://www.nitinh.com/2009/02/why-django-orm-sucks-it-takes-a-hell-lot-of-memory-in-processing/

Comment: how much memory do you have allocated for memcached?

Comment: That means it is not caching it is going into if condition every time @DanielRoseman

Comment: i just added 100 M in in conf file @chaos

Comment: if divided the data into two chunks it is working like result[:40000] with one cache and result[40000:] with another cache. But while taking entire records it is not caching the data. @DanielRoseman